# There are $E, F \in \mathcal{M}$ satisfying $E \subset A \subset F$ and $\mu (F \backslash E) = 0.$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X, \mathcal{M}, \mu)$ be a complete measure space. Show that if $A \in \mathcal{M},$ then there are $E, F \in \mathcal{M}$ satisfying $E \subset A \subset F$ and $\mu (F \backslash E) = 0.$

My efforts: Since $A \in \mathcal{M}$ then $A = B \cup C,$ where $B \in \mathcal{M}$ and $C \subset N,$ with $\mu(N) = 0.$ Let $E = B$ and $F = B \cup N.$ Therefore, $E \subset A \subset F$ and $\mu (F \backslash E) \leq \mu(N) = 0.$

Is that correct?

**Edit problem statement:**

Let $(X, \mathcal{M}, \mu)$ be a measure space and $(X, \bar{\mathcal{M}}, \bar{\mu})$ its completion. Show that $A \in \bar{\mathcal{M}}$ then $\exists E, F \in \mathcal{M}$ satisfying $E \subset A \subset F$ and $\mu (F \backslash E) = 0.$

Comment: Take $E=F=A$.  Then $F\setminus E$ is empty.

Comment: Thank you. But is there a problem with my solution?

Comment: One slight issue with this is that there is an implicit assumption that there are measure zero (non-empty) sets. Not every measure space has these.

Comment: What's the _definition_ of $\overline{\mathcal M}$?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich see here the definition of completion.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/749159/definition-of-completion-of-a-measure-space

Comment: Have you looked at that definition? In fact the thing you want to prove for $A\in\overline{\mathcal M}$ is literally the definition of $A\in\overline{\mathcal M}$!

Answer (score 0):

The OP says that the definition of the completion of a measure space in force here is the definition [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/749159/definition-of-completion-of-a-measure-space).

If you look at that definition you see that what we need to prove here is this:

> **Exercise.** If $A\in\overline{\mathcal M}$ then $A\in\overline{\mathcal M}$.

(Presumably in whatever context the question came from the completion was actually given a formally different definition?)