# Completing a measure space does not affect the integrability of a function

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, measure-theory, banach-spaces, bochner-spaces

Let $(X, \mathcal A, \mu)$ be a measure space and $(E, | \cdot |)$ a Banach space.

- $f \in E^{X}$ is called $\mu$-**simple** if $f = \sum_{k=1}^n e_k 1_{A_k}$ where $e_k \in E$ and $(A_k)_{k=1}^n$ is a finite sequence of pairwise disjoint sets with finite measure in $\mathcal A$. The integral of such $f$ w.r.t. $\mu$  is defined by $\int_{X} f \mathrm d \mu := \sum_{k=1}^n e_k \mu(A_k)$. Let $\mathcal S (X, \mu, E)$ be the space of such $\mu$-simple functions.  We define a semi-norm $\|\cdot\|_1$ on $\mathcal S (X, \mu, E)$ by $\|f\|_1 :=\int_{X} |f| \mathrm d \mu$. The notion of Cauchy sequence is thus applicable for $(\mathcal S (X, \mu, E), \| \cdot \|_1)$.
- $f \in E^{X}$ is called $\mu$-**measurable** if $f$ is a $\mu$-a.e. limit of a sequence $(f_n) \subset \mathcal S (X, \mu, E)$.  Let $\mathcal L_0 (X, \mu, E)$ be the space of such $\mu$-measurable functions.
- $f \in E^{X}$ is called $\mu$-**integrable** if $f$ is $\mu$-a.e. limit of a Cauchy sequence $(f_n) \subset \mathcal S (X, \mu, E)$. The integral of such $f$ w.r.t. $\mu$  is defined by $\int_{X} f \mathrm d \mu := \lim_n \int_{X} f_n \mathrm d \mu$. Let $\mathcal L_1 (X, \mu, E)$ be the space of such $\mu$-integrable functions. We also define a semi-norm $\|\cdot\|_1$ on $\mathcal L_1 (X, \mu, E)$ by $\| f\|_1 :=  \int_{X} |f| \mathrm d \mu$.

Previously, I proved that

> [Theorem 1:](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4507633/completing-a-measure-space-does-not-affect-the-strong-measurability-of-a-functio) Let $(X, \mathcal A', \mu')$ be the [completion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_measure) of $(X, \mathcal A, \mu)$. A function $f \in E^X$ is $\mu$-measurable if and only if $f$ is $\mu'$-measurable.

Now I try to prove below complementary result, i.e.,

> **Theorem 2:** Let $(X, \mathcal A', \mu')$ be the [completion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_measure) of $(X, \mathcal A, \mu)$. A function $f \in E^X$ is $\mu$-integrable if and only if $f$ is $\mu'$-integrable.

Could you have a check on my attempt?

---

**My attempt:** Let $\mathcal Z$ be the collection of all subsets of the $\mu$-null subsets of $X$.

Because $\mathcal A \subset \mathcal A'$ and $\mu' \restriction \mathcal A = \mu$, the direction $\implies$ then follows. Let's prove the reverse direction. Fix a $\mu'$-integrable function $f$. There is a Cauchy sequence $(f_n) \subset \mathcal S (X, \mu', E)$ such that $f_n \to f$ $\mu'$-a.e.

Assume $f_n = \sum_{i=1}^{\varphi (n)} e_{ni} 1_{A_{ni}}$ with $(A_{ni})_{i=1}^{\varphi (n)}$ a finite sequence of pairwise disjoint sets with finite measure in $\mathcal A'$. By construction of $\mathcal A'$, [there exist](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/713140/368425) $B_{ni} \in \mathcal A$ and $C_{ni} \in \mathcal Z$ such that $A_{ni} = B_{ni} \cup C_{ni}$ and $\mu(B_{ni}) = \mu'(A_{ni}) < \infty$. Let $g_n := \sum_{i=1}^{\varphi (n)} e_{ni} 1_{B_{ni}}$. Then $(g_n) \subset \mathcal S (X, \mu, E)$.

1. $g_n \to f$ $\mu$-a.e.

Let $N'$ be a $\mu'$-null set such that $f_n \to f$ on $(N')^c$. Notice that $\{x \in X \mid f_n (x) \neq g_n (x)\} \subset C_n :=\bigcup_{i=1}^{\varphi (n)} C_{ni}$. Let $N'' := N' \cup \bigcup_n C_n$. Then $N''$ is a $\mu'$-null set. It follows that $g_n \to f$ on $A :=(N'')^c$. [There exist](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/713140/368425) $B \in \mathcal A$ and $C \in \mathcal Z$ such that $A = B \cup C$ and $\mu(B) = \mu'(A) = 1$. It follows that $g_n \to f$ on $B$.

2. $(g_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence.

Let $\| \cdot \|_1$ and $\| \cdot \|_1'$ be the semi-norms of $\mathcal S (X, \mu, E)$ and $\mathcal S (X, \mu', E)$ respectively. Notice that $\mathcal S (X, \mu, E) \subset \mathcal S (X, \mu', E)$, so $(g_n) \subset \mathcal S (X, \mu', E)$. We have
$$
\begin{align}
\|f_n-f_m\|_1' &= \|(f_n - g_n) - (f_m - g_m) + (g_n-g_m)\|_1' \\
&\le \|f_n - g_n\|_1' +\| f_m - g_m \|_1'+ \|g_n-g_m\|_1' .
\end{align}
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
\|f_n-f_m\|_1' &= \|(f_n - g_n) - (f_m - g_m) + (g_n-g_m)\|_1' \\
&\ge \|g_n-g_m\|_1'  - \|f_n - g_n\|_1' - \| f_m - g_m \|_1'.
\end{align}
$$

We have
$$
\|f_n - g_n\|_1' \le \sum_{i=1}^{\varphi (n)} \|e_{ni} 1_{C_{ni}}\|_1' = \sum_{i=1}^{\varphi (n)} |e_{ni}| \mu'(C_{ni}) = 0.
$$

Similarly, $\|f_m - g_m\|_1' \le 0$. Also,
$$
\|g_n-g_m\|_1' = \|g_n-g_m\|_1.
$$

It follows that $\|g_n-g_m\|_1 = \|f_n-f_m\|_1'$. This completes the proof.