# Lebesgue integral coincides with Bochner integral if the former is finite

Tags: integration, measure-theory, bochner-spaces

Let $(X, \mathcal A, \mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space and $E := [0, \infty]$ endowed with [order topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line#Order_and_topological_properties).

- $f \in E^{X}$ is called $\mu$-**simple** if $f = \sum_{k=1}^n e_k 1_{A_k}$ where $e_k \in E \setminus \{\infty\}$ and $(A_k)_{k=1}^n$ is a finite sequence of pairwise disjoint sets with finite measure in $\mathcal A$. The **Bochner integral** of such $f$ w.r.t. $\mu$  is defined by $\int f := \sum_{k=1}^n e_k \mu(A_k)$. Let $\mathcal S (X, \mu, E)$ be the space of $\mu$-simple functions.
- $f \in E^{X}$ is called $\mathcal A$-**measurable** if $f^{-1} (O) \in \mathcal A$ for every open subset $O$ of $E$.
- $f \in E^{X}$ is called $\mu$-**measurable** if $f$ is a $\mu$-a.e. limit of a sequence $(f_n) \subset \mathcal S (X, \mu, E)$. Let $\mathcal L_0 (X, \mu, E)$ be the space of such $\mu$-measurable functions.

> [Lemma 1:](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4508509/non-complete-measure-spaces-approximate-a-mu-measurable-function-valued-in) $f \in E^X$ is $\mu$-measurable if and only if there is an increasing sequence $(f_n) \subset \mathcal S (X, \mu, E)$ such that $f_n \nearrow f$ $\mu$-a.e.

- For a $\mu$-measurable function $f \in E^X$, by **Lemma 1** there is an increasing sequence $(f_n) \subset \mathcal S (X, \mu, E)$ such that $f_n \nearrow f$ $\mu$-a.e. Then **Lebesgue integral** of such $f$ is defined as $\oint f := \lim_n \int f_n$ and is *independent* of the approximating sequence $(f_n)$.
- $f \in E^{X}$ is called $\mu$-**integrable** if $f$ is a $\mu$-a.e. limit of a Cauchy sequence $(f_n) \subset \mathcal S (X, \mu, E)$. The **Bochner integral** of such $f$ w.r.t. $\mu$  is defined by $\int f := \lim_n \int f_n$ and is *independent* of the approximating sequence $(f_n)$.

> **Lemma 2:** Let $f,g \in E^X$ be $\mu$-integrable such that $f \le g$ $\mu$-a.e. Then $\int f \le \int g$.

- Let $\mathcal L_1 (X, \mu, E)$ be the space of $\mu$-integrable functions. Clearly, $\mathcal L_1 (X, \mu, E) \subset \mathcal L_0 (X, \mu, E)$.

I'm trying to prove the equivalence between these two types of integrals

> **Theorem**: If $f \in \mathcal L_1 (X, \mu, E)$ then $\int f = \oint f$. If $f \in \mathcal L_0 (X, \mu, E)$ such that $\oint f < \infty$ then $f \in \mathcal L_1 (X, \mu, E)$ and $\int f = \oint f$.

Could you have a check on my proof?

---

**My attempt:**

1. Let $f$ be $\mu$-integrable.

Then $f$ is $\mu$-measurable. There is a sequence $(f_n) \subset \mathcal S (X, \mu, E)$ such that $f_n \nearrow f$ $\mu$-a.e. We have $\oint f = \lim_n \int f_n$. It suffices to show that $(f_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence. It follows from $f_n \le f$ and **Lemma 2** that $\int f_n \le \int f$. Taking the limit $n \to \infty$, we get $\oint f_n \le \int f <\infty$. Fix $\varepsilon>0$, there is $N$ such that
$$
\oint f - \int f_n=\left | \oint f - \int f_n\right | <\varepsilon \quad \forall n >N.
$$

Then
$$
\|f_n-f_m\|_1 = \int |f_n-f_m| = \int f_m - \int f_n \le \oint f - \int f_n  < \varepsilon \quad \forall m \ge n > N.
$$

It follows that $(f_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence.

2. Let $\oint f < \infty$.

Let $(f_n) \subset \mathcal S (X, \mu, E)$ such that $f_n \nearrow f$ $\mu$-a.e. Then $\oint f = \lim_n \int f_n < \infty$. Fix $\varepsilon>0$, there is $N$ such that
$$
\oint f - \int f_n=\left | \oint f - \int f_n\right | <\varepsilon \quad \forall n >N.
$$

Then
$$
\|f_n-f_m\|_1 = \int |f_n-f_m| = \int f_m - \int f_n \le \oint f - \int f_n  < \varepsilon \quad \forall m \ge n > N.
$$

It follows that $(f_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence. Then $\int f =\lim_n \int f_n$. This completes the proof.