# Pushforward measure: change-of-variables formula for Banach spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, banach-spaces, bochner-spaces, pushforward

I'm trying to strengthen my understanding of Bochner integral by extending [change-of-variables formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_measure#Main_property:_change-of-variables_formula) to Banach spaces, i.e.,

> **Theorem:** Let $(X, \mathcal X, \mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space, $(Y, \mathcal Y)$ a measurable space, $\pi:X \to Y$ measurable, and $(E, |\cdot|)$ a Banach space. Here we use [Bochner integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4298588/dominated-convergence-theorem-for-banach-space). Let $\nu := \pi_\sharp \mu$ and $f \in L_0(Y, \nu, E)$. Then $f \in L_1 (Y, \nu, E)$ if and only if $f \circ \pi \in L_1(X, \mu, E)$. In this case,
> $$
> \int_X (f \circ \pi) \mathrm d \mu = \int_Y f \mathrm d \nu \quad (\star).
> $$

Could you have a check on my attempt? Thank you so much!

**Proof:**

> 1. $E := [0, \infty]$.

We have $f \in L_0 (Y, \nu, E)$ [if and only if](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4508509/non-complete-measure-spaces-approximate-a-0-infty-valued-mu-measurable) there is an increasing sequence $(f_n) \subset \mathcal S (Y, \nu, E)$ such that $f_n \to f$ $\nu$-a.e. It follows that $(f_n \circ \pi)$ is increasing and $f_n \circ \pi \to f \circ \pi$ $\mu$-a.e. By [definition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4508736/lesbegue-integral-coincides-with-bochner-integral-if-the-former-is-finite?noredirect=1&lq=1),
$$
\int_X (f \circ \pi) \mathrm d \mu = \lim_n \int_X (f_n \circ \pi) \mathrm d \mu \quad \text{and} \quad \int_Y f \mathrm d \nu = \lim_n \int_Y f_n \mathrm d \nu.
$$

Because $(\star)$ trivially holds for $\mu$-simple functions, we get
$$
\int_X (f \circ \pi) \mathrm d \mu = \int_Y f \mathrm d \nu.
$$

Our reasoning also shows that $f \in L_1 (Y, \nu, E) \iff f \circ \pi \in L_1(X, \mu, E)$.

> 2. $E$ is a Banach space.

We have $f \in L_1 (Y, \nu, E)$ [if and only if](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4299760/equivalent-integrability-criteria-f-in-mathcall-1x-mu-e-if-and-onl) $|f| \in L_1 (Y, \nu, [0, \infty))$. Similarly, $f \circ \pi \in L_1(X, \mu, E)$ if and only if $|f| \circ \pi \in L_1(X, \mu, [0, \infty))$. We apply **(1.)** on $|f|$ to get the integrability equivalence between $f$ and $f \circ \pi$. Next we prove $(\star)$.

> a. $f$ is $\nu$-simple.

Then $f = \sum_{i=1}^n e_i 1_{A_i}$ for some $e_i \in E\setminus \{0\}$ and $A_i \in \mathcal Y$ such that $(e_i)$ is pairwise different and $\nu(A_i) <\infty$. It follows that $f \circ \pi$ is $\mu$-simple. In fact, $f \circ g = \sum_{i=1}^n e_i 1_{B_i}$ with $B_i := \pi^{-1} (A_i)$. Notice that $\mu(B_i) = \mu(\pi^{-1} (A_i)) = \nu(A_i) < \infty$ It's clear that $(\star)$ holds.

> b. $f \in L_1 (Y, \nu, E)$.

By [definition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4298588/dominated-convergence-theorem-for-banach-space), there is a Cauchy sequence $(f_n)$ of $\nu$-simple functions such that $f_n \to f$ $\nu$-a.e. As shown in **(2.a.)**, $f_n \circ \pi$ is $\mu$-simple. It's clear that $f_n \circ \pi \to f \circ \pi$ $\mu$-a.e. Let's prove that $(f_n \circ \pi)$ is Cauchy. Indeed,
$$
\begin{align}
\|f_n \circ \pi - f_m \circ \pi\|_{L_1} = \|(f_n-f_m) \circ \pi\|_{L_1} = \int_X |(f_n-f_m) \circ \pi| \mathrm d \mu =  \int_X |f_n-f_m| \circ \pi \mathrm d \mu.
\end{align}
$$

Notice that $|f_n-f_m|$ is $\nu$-simple. By **(2.a.)**,
$$
\int_X |f_n-f_m| \circ \pi \mathrm d \mu = \int_Y |f_n-f_m| \mathrm d  \nu = \|f_n-f_m\|_{L_1}.
$$

As such, $(f_n \circ \pi)$ is a Cauchy sequence. By [definition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4298588/dominated-convergence-theorem-for-banach-space),
$$
\int_X (f \circ \pi) \mathrm d \mu = \lim_n \int_X (f_n \circ \pi) \mathrm d \mu \quad \text{and} \quad \int_Y f \mathrm d \nu = \lim_n \int_Y f_n \mathrm d \nu.
$$

By **(2.a.)**, we have
$$
\int_X (f_n \circ \pi) \mathrm d \mu = \int_Y f_n \mathrm d \nu \quad \forall n.
$$

Then $(\star)$ follows.