# If $B$ is a Brownian motion independent of $X$, then $B$ is still a Brownian motion under the regular conditional probability given $X$

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability, brownian-motion, independence

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathbb P)$ be a probability space. Let $B$ be a one-dimensional Brownian motion. Let $X, Y:\Omega\to \mathbb R$ be random variables.

Let $\nu: \mathbb R \times \mathcal F \to [0, 1]$ be a [regular conditional probability](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4664244/368425) of $\mathcal F$ given $X$, i.e.,

- for every $x \in \mathbb R$, we have $\nu(x, \cdot)$ is a probability measure on $(\Omega, \mathcal F)$,
- for every $A \in \mathcal F$, we have $\nu(\cdot, A)$ is $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$-measurable.
- for every $A \in \mathcal F$ and $C \in \mathcal B(\mathbb R)$,
  $$
  \mathbb P [A \cap \{X \in C\}] = \int_C \nu(x, A) \ \mathrm d (X_\sharp \mathbb P) (x),
  $$
  where $X_\sharp \mathbb P$ is the push-forward of $\mathbb P$ by $X$.

Then we have a straightforward result, i.e.,

> **Theorem** If $X,Y,B$ are pairwise independent under $\mathbb P$, then $Y, B$ are [conditionally independent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4664244/can-we-characterize-conditional-independence-by-conditional-probability) given $X$.
>
> **Proof** Let $E := \mathcal C([0, \infty); \mathbb R)$ be the space of paths of $B$. Let $A \in \mathcal B (\mathbb R)$ and $C \in\mathcal B (E)$. By [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4664287/368425) lemma,
> $$
> \begin{align}
> \nu(X, \{Y\in A\} \cap \{B \in C\}) &= \mathbb P [\{Y\in A\} \cap \{B \in C\} |X] 
> \quad \text{a.s.} \\
> \nu(X, \{Y\in A\}) &= \mathbb P [Y\in A | X]  \quad \text{a.s.},\\
> \nu(X, \{B\in C\}) &= \mathbb P [B\in C | X]  \quad \text{a.s.}
> \end{align}
> $$
> By pairwise independence of $X,Y,B$,
> $$
> \begin{align}
> \mathbb P [\{Y\in A\} \cap \{B \in C\} |X] &= \mathbb P [Y\in A ] \cdot \mathbb P [ B \in C] \quad \text{a.s.}, \\
> \mathbb P [Y\in A | X] &=  \mathbb P [Y\in A] \quad \text{a.s.},\\
> \mathbb P [B\in C | X] &=  \mathbb P [B\in C] \quad \text{a.s.}
> \end{align}
> $$
> The claim then follows.

It is mentioned in [this](https://mathoverflow.net/a/443213/99469) answer that

> Here independence of $B$ from $X$ guarantees that $B$ is still an independent collection of Brownian motions under each $\nu (x, \cdot)$.

Could you explain how to prove above statement?